# Move semantics c++ singly linked list

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics, assignment-operator

I have been learning about move semantics in c++ and i think i have got my head around it.
Just to be sure i was wondering if anyone could give me some tips or even give me suggestions to improve my code. Thanks :)

I am implementing a dictionary as a linked list for an assignment if you are wondering why i wouldnt use a binary tree or anything else for that matter.

```
template<class Key, class Item>
Dictionary<Key, Item>::Dictionary(const Dictionary& original)
{
    std::cout << "Copy Constructor Invoked" << std::endl;
    this->root = deepCopy(original.root);

}

template<class Key, class Item>
Dictionary<Key, Item>& Dictionary<Key, Item>::operator=(const Dictionary& original)
{
    //Check if objects are of the same type.
    if (this == &original)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    root = deepCopy(original.root);
    return *this;
}

template<class Key, class Item>
Dictionary<Key, Item>::Dictionary(Dictionary&& original)
{
    std::cout << "Move Constructor" << std::endl;
    this->root = deepCopy(original.root);
    original.root = nullptr;
    deepDelete(original.root);

}

template<class Key, class Item>
Dictionary<Key, Item>& Dictionary<Key, Item>::operator=(Dictionary&& original)
{
    //Check if objects are of the same type.
    if (this == &original)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    std::cout << "Move Operator" << std::endl;

    root = original.root;
    original.root = nullptr;
    deepDelete(original.root);
    return *this;
}

template<class Key, class Item>
inline Dictionary<Key, Item>::~Dictionary()
{
    deepDelete(root);
}
```

Comment: I think the proper channel for this request is: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please could you reword your question? It is not clear what you are asking: you shouldn't be asking for a general "code review" or "hints and tips". Is there something specific you would like to ask about? If so, please reword to ask that.

Comment: Moving should not deep-copy and delete, it should just "steal" the contents. (Also, you're leaking the entire original tree.)

Comment: The comment `//Check if objects are of the same type.` is wrong. You're checking if they are the same object, which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 2):

A move constructor shouldn't usually perform a "deep copy". It should make a shallow copy, and then restore the original object into a state that enforces any class invariants. If there are no invariants, then a shallow copy alone is sufficient (in which case the implicitly generated move constructor does what you want).

Furthermore, you're passing nullptr to `deepDelete`, which makes no sense to me.

Intuitively, a sensible move constructor would be like this:

```
this->root = original.root; // shallow copy
original.root = nullptr;    // enforce class invariant of unique ownership
```